# How to avoid Qt to execute QAbstractButton::nextCheckState() when checkable button is clicked?

Tags: c++, qt

When you click a checkable button. The checkstate always inverts:
on to off
off to on

This is because when a checkable button is clicked Qt calls the nextcheckstate function.

```cpp
QAbstractButton::nextCheckState()
```

Is there a way to avoid that? (I would like to decide check state by myself)

In my mind I would have to do the following steps to avoid that:

1. Create a MyPushButton Class which inherits QPushButton
2. Declare in mypushbutton.h an override function which overwrites the function when a checkable button is clicked
3. Somehow suppress calling QAbstractButton::nextCheckState() in that overriding function

Does somebody know which function to override?

Comment: `nextCheckState` is virtual. You can override it and, for example, do nothing in your override.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Checkablebutton->blockSignals(true); // Maybe nextCheckState() is not call from now on until BlockSingls(false)

//some code

Checkablebutton->blockSignals(false);
```